# Can't connect to Oracle DB, error 12541 : No Listener

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener

I am having an issue connecting to a remote database, I have an error with tnsping :

```
tnsping QT
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myurl.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=mySvc)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

My tnsnames.ora :

```
QT=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dv32myrdb.ft.fr)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=mySvc)))
```

`TNS_ADMIN` env variable is set to the folder which contains `tnsnames` file :

```
C:\oracle11\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin
```

I also added the Oracle client folder to `PATH` variable :

```
C:\oracle11\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin
```

I know server side is OK since I can connect from another client with sqlplus.

Here is my spec :

- Windows 10
- Oracle Client 11.2.0
- Oracle DB 11g

It just seems something is badly configured but I have no clue what it is.
The DB is in a VLAN in which I am currently in.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Maybe some firewall or proxy setting on server side reject your connection, IP is blocked due secure reasons.

Comment: Indeed, it was a proxy behind the VM which were refusing all undeclared connections. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.